# not result to fetch error when iterating through different tables with psycopg

Tags: python-3.x, psycopg2

I want to export several tables  to *.json* file. First, I have query for those tables I want, matching some condition, the second query, build the *json* object that I want to store. I am using *psycopg2*, but when it runs, the loop for the 1st item do its job, and then when the 2nd item in the list is starting it returns:

> no results to fetch

```
    try:
    
        connection = psycopg2.connect(user...)
    
    
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            try:
                cursor = connection.cursor()
                cursor.execute(
                    "SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.views WHERE table_schema = 'public' and table_name LIKE 'text%' ORDER BY table_name ASC;")
                tablenames = cursor.fetchall()
                table_names_list = [row[0] for row in tablenames]
                for table in table_names_list:
                    print(table)
                    query=(
                        " SELECT jsonb_build_object( ...) AS feature FROM ( SELECT * FROM {tb} LIMIT 10) inputs ".format(tb=table))
                    sql_to_file=("COPY ({0}) TO STDOUT").format(query)
                    rows=cursor.fetchall()
                    filename = "%s.json" % table
                    print('File: ' + filename + ' created')
                    with open(filename, "w") as f:
                        cursor.copy_expert(sql_to_file, f)
                connection.commit()
            except Exception as e:
                connection.rollback()
                print(e)
    except (Exception, psycopg2.Error) as error:
        print("Error while fetching data from PostgreSQL", error)
    
    finally:
        # closing database connection.
        if connection:
            cursor.close()
            connection.close()
            print("PostgreSQL connection is closed")
```

I have tried to follow some instruction in the [*psypcopg2* site](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html) and some other [threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55400707/python3-psycopg2-no-results-to-fetch-using-returning), but cannot find information regarding this error or how to solve it.

Comment: @snakecharmerb if i use a print (table) after the for table to print the table names it is returning me results for the first item of the list the list with the object correctly built as per the second query, it does all the process, then the second one name appear and then breaks because said not results to fetch.

Comment: To me it looks like `rows=cursor.fetchall()` is the issue.  The earlier `tablenames = cursor.fetchall()` would have fetched all the rows which would result in `rows=cursor.fetchall()`  failing with `no results to fetch`. So either you are missing another `cursor.execute()` or `rows=cursor.fetchall()` should not be there.